# Install and Run the android app in the higher version?

Tags: android, api, installation

Is it possible to run the android app in higher version ? if i create any app using the API level 7 and try to run it on API level 8 or 9 ..it does not show the AVD(emulator) of that API level in the run Target..How can i make an app which will install and run properly in different different version..

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ya you can do it higher version.
like this ::

just

`right click on property >> android >> chose target which you want >> ok >> run`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe u can make Project>properties>android then select to target device or u can down your project level!
If you want to work your app for all apis your project support the bt apis